# access raspberry pi with wifi, without ethernet cable

Tags: wifi, ethernet, vnc, remote, desktop

Hi guys I'm trying to access my raspberry pi through the remote desktop / vnc viewer without ethernet cable but only with wifi. And it connects only rarely and if it doesn't I get the error:
Remote Desktop cannot connect to the remote computer for one of the following reasons

1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
2. The remote computer is turned off
3. The remote computer is unavailable on the network

or sometimes "connection timed out"

I'd be really thankful for any help you can provide

Comment: Have you tried after booting without the ethernet cable?  You need to provide far more information about how you have setup the network.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote desktop" ? How are you trying to connect?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly are you trying to connect in both cases? Copy&paste the error message to your question. In case you use an IP address: Your Raspberry Pi probably gets different IP addresses for ethernet and WiFi.

Comment: Have you disabled WiFi power management `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`?

Comment: @joan thanks a lot! I had set up the pi with the ethernet cable. As a consequence the wifi only connected through the computer and not directly to the hotspot.

Comment: @Dougie my wifi is indeed really slow so that it often gives me an error like "connection timed out" so that i have to reconnect. Can I enter that command of which you spoke in the command promt window in the interface of the raspberrypi?

Comment: You can enter that command on any valid terminal.

Comment: if you can then first check if remote access works with ethernet cable. If it works then all problem is only your wifi.